# How do I get just the header from a TYPO3 content element rendered to my custom layout?

Tags: typo3

I am using `<f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>{contentAbout}</f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>` which gets both Header and Text.

Comment: Could you please specify the origin of the variable `{contentAbout}`?  What results do you get if you add `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>` into your Fluid Template?

Comment: addional information about your system is helpful: what software in which version do you use?

Comment: It seems that `{contentAbout}` contains all content elements in one column. For this you need to change the template of the content element itself.